# Return Documents with Same Subarray elements

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have the following collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "tags" : [ "school", "home" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "tags" : [ "school", "storage", "home" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "tags" : [ "school", "storage", "home", "bones" ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "tags" : [ "school", "storage", "home", "bones", "milk" ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "tags" : [ "homes", "maps", "bones" ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "tags" : [ "xxx", "yyy", "zzz" ] }
```

I would like to return all documents where "tags" matches documents with exactly the same array elements.

So thus, if I were to query for tags == ["school", "home"] or tags == ["home", "school"], document w/ _id=1 would be returned

I am doing the following:

```
db.test.find({tags: {$in: ['school', 'home']}}) or 
db.test.find({tags: {$in: ['home', 'school']}})
```

and the following are returned:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "tags" : [ "school", "home" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "tags" : [ "school", "storage", "home" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "tags" : [ "school", "storage", "home", "bones" ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "tags" : [ "school", "storage", "home", "bones", "milk" ] }
```

How may I achieve only item w/ _id=1 be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

Option 1:

```
 db.collection.find({
  $and: [
 {
  tags: "school"
 },
 {
  tags: "home"
 },
 {
  tags: {
      $size: 2
    }
 }
 ]
})
```

Explained:

Match if school & home are in the tags array and if array size is 2.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wjlLUpbC1f8)

Option 2:

```
db.collection.find({
 $or: [
  {
    tags: [
    "school",
    "home"
  ]
  },
  {
  tags: [
    "home",
    "school"
  ]
  }
 ]
})
```

Explained:

Match the two possible array options

[Playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FeiBDlKChba)

Comment: Just added option 2 I think is maybe more suitable ...

Comment: So the first way worked for me, unfortunately the array will be a variable array. I did it a little differently based on Option 2:


db.test.find({$and: [{tags: {$in: ['school', 'home']}}, {tags: {$size: 2}}]})

Comment: Ah yeah , working as well ... , just when it is $in you can match cases like ["school" ,"other_unwanted"]